# postgresql-group by- complex query

Tags: postgresql

Here's what my table TheTable looks like

```
ColA  | ColB  | 
------+-------+------
abc   | 2005  | 
abc   | 2010  | 
def   | 2009  | 
def   | 2010  | 
def   | 2011  | 
abc   | 2012  |
```

And I want to write a query to return this result:

```
ColA  | ColB  | ColC
------+-------+------
abc   | 2005  | 2010
def   | 2009  | 2011
abc   | 2012  |  -
```

Comment: what about *def   | 2011  |*  and *abc   | 2012  |* ?

Comment: If you are tryning to implement " SCD type 2", then your data model shown in the question is incomplete and doesn't allow for queries like this. See this link for details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2).

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? I can't see any way to generate the result you want from the input given.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get the results you want using window functions and a nested subquery:

```
select "ColA"
, max(case when parity = 0 then "ColB" end) as "ColB"
, max(case when parity = 1 then "ColB" end) as "ColC"
from (
 select * 
  , (rank() over(partition by "ColA" order by "ColB" asc) - 1)
  , (rank() over(partition by "ColA" order by "ColB" asc) - 1) / 2 as result_row
  , (rank() over(partition by "ColA" order by "ColB" asc) - 1) % 2 as parity

 from TheTable ) t

GROUP BY "ColA", result_row
```